# Switch inside loops impacting performance?

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style

I'm in a scenario where I'm looping through data and formatting it in specific ways based on a setting, and I'm concerned that what I feel is best stylistically might impede performance.

The basic pattern of the code is as follows

```
enum setting {single, multiple, foo, bar};
Data data = getData(Connection conn, int id);
setting blah = data.getSetting();
foreach (Item item in data)
{
   switch(blah)
   {
      case blah.single:
        processDataSingle(item blah);
        break;
      ...
   }
}
```

My concern is that there might be thousands, or even tens of thousands of items in data. I was wondering if having the switch inside the loop where it may be evaluated repeatedly might cause some serious performance issues. I know I could put the `switch` before the loop, but then each `case` contains it, which seems much less readable, in that it's less apparent that the basic function remains the same.

Comment: Can you post the full switch? We'd be able to advise the best solution if we knew the **exact** functioning of the code

Comment: Have you done a performance test? Make the 2 solutions, use a lot of data >1000, and time it :)

Comment: Sometimes splitting the workload according to `blah` and (concurrently) processing the now-uniform 'shards' is effective. Impossible to tell from the posted code, though

Comment: Have you profiled the code and determined that this is indeed your bottleneck?

Comment: This code makes no sense. It seems like it is a completely backward approach to the problem, but since we don't really know what the problem is (too abstract), there's not much that can be done...

Comment: I haven't finished writing the code yet, sadly. I thought of it as a potential bottleneck as I was working on building the various cases. (This setting is a new feature).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set up a delegate/action once, then call it every time in the loop:

```
Data data = getData(Connection conn, int id);
setting blah = data.getSetting();
Action<Item> doThis;
switch (blah)
{
  case blah.single:
      doThis = i => processSingleData(i blah);
      break;
  ...
}
foreach (Item item in data)
{
    doThis(item);
}
```

Basically, put the body of each "case" in an `Action`, select that `Action` in your `switch` outside the loop, and call the `Action` in the loop.

Comment: Oooh, I like this idea. It seems to have both the readability I was looking for and increased performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method  to keep readability, then pass the data to the method:

```
void processAllData(IEnumerable<Item> data,  setting blah)
{
    switch(blah)
    {
      case blah.single:
        foreach (Item item in data)
        {

        }
    }
    // next case, next loop ...
}
```

Then it's just a one-liner:

```
processAllData(data, blah);
```

This approach is readable since it encapsulates complexity, concise since you only see what you have to see and efficient since you can optimize the cases.

Comment: Doesn't this just move the issue from one place to another?

Comment: @Sconibulus: It increases readability but does not affect performance. If code gets more and more complex you should refactor it. The easiest way is to extract methods. This hides complexity and also allows to reuse it. Edit: But maybe you want to combine it with Rawlings approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

By using a Action delegate this way, you can factorize your code a lot

```
enum setting {single, multiple, foo, bar};
Data data = getData(Connection conn, int id);

var processAll = new Action<Action<item>>(action =>
                    {
                        foreach(var item in data)                           
                            action(item);
                    });

setting blah = data.getSetting();

switch(blah)
{
    case blah.single:
       processAll(item => processDataSingle(item, blah));
       break;
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It certainly does have the potential to affect performance if you're talking about possibly running the comparison tens of thousands of times or more. The other problem that could potentially arise in the code that you've written here is what happens if you need to add to your enum. Then you'd need to open up this code and adjust it to take care of that circumstance, which violates the [Open/Closed Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html).

The best way, IMO, to solve both problems at once would be to use a Factory pattern to take care of this (see posts [here](http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/factory-pattern-with-reflection-c/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164170.aspx) for some advice on starting that). All you'd need to do is have an interface whose implementations would call the method that you'd want to call in your switch code above. Create a factory and have it pick which implementation to return back to your code (before the loop) based on the enum passed in. At that point all your loop needs to do is to call that interface method which will do exactly what you wanted.

Afterwards, any future feature additions will only require you to create another implementation of that interface, and adjust the enum accordingly. No muss, no fuss.

Comment: The enum is actually a private thing I created to improve identification of the meanings of values pulled down through the Setting field, so the code has to be opened anyway. I'll keep this in mind for when I refactor this and similar processes.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly slower to put the switch in the loop like that. Whether it's significant or not is impossible to say - use a Stopwatch to see.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the switch statement are near one to another, the compiler will produce a lookup table instead of N `if` statements. It increases performance, but it's hard to say when the compiler will decide to do this.
Instead you can create a `Dictionary<switchType,Delegate>`, populate it with pairs of value-action, and then selecting the appropriate action will take about `O(1)` as dictionary is a hash table.
`dictionary[value].Invoke()`.